# Dynamic DNS and URL really slow to load from the internal network

Tags: networking, router, dns, nat, dynamic-dns

I have a Docker Nextcloud instance running on my PC where I configured it in a way that the application server running upon it points to `https://myid.duckdns.org:1234`.
Of course the `duckdns.org` client to refresh the IP value is installed and scheduled on my PC so that that URL points always to my PC.
Everything has always worked fine and I could access `https://myid.duckdns.org:1234` directly from my PC without any issue.

Now, from a couple of days, I am not able to correctly access that URL from my PC, meaning that the page takes really **a lot** of time to load even the first simple Nextcloud login page (or it does not load at all).

If I access `https://myid.duckdns.org:1234` from a phone **not** connected to my home network it works just fine, so from outside it works, it does not when connected to the internal network, though.

If I `ping myid.duckdns.org` it answers fast and gives the correct public IP of my PC.

I have recently added a router to my home Network by it just acts as an AP (I disabled DHCP on it, and gave it a static IP), it takes the WAN configuration from the main router (bridged interface) so it should not be the bottleneck, especially because I tried to skip it by connecting my PC back directly to the main router and I have the same issue.

What could be the issue here in your opinion?
What other test could I make to find the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Just a thought, but maybe a local DNS server might help? Have it point to the local IP of `myid.duckdns.org` and forward all other requests to your ISP or whomever. The main router would use the local DNS server in this case.

Comment: @Anaksunaman, sorry I'm not sure I got how to do that actually! Could you please be more specific? Thanks